# Cannot read property 'variable' of undefined (Typescript / HTML / Nativescript)

Tags: android, typescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm coding a Nativescript-Angular2-Typescript App but currently run always into a TypeError.

The now following code is already adjusted to debug purposes.

login.component.html

```
    <StackLayout>
    <Image src="res://icon" stretch="none" horizontalAlignment="center"></Image>
    <TextField [(ngModel)]="user.phonenr" hint="mobile phone number" keyboardType="phone" autocorrect="false"></TextField>
    <TextField hint="SMS code" secure="true"></TextField>
    <Button text="login" class="submit-button" (tap)="submitnr()"></Button>
    <Button text="register" class="btn"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
```

login.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from "@angular/core";
    import { Button } from "tns-core-modules/ui/button";
    import { User } from '../../shared/user/user';
    import { UserService } from "../../shared/user/user.service";


    @Component({
    selector: "Login",
    providers: [UserService],
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
    styleUrls: ['./login-common.css']
    })

    export class LoginComponent {

    //Variables
    public user: User;       

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    this.user = new User();
    this.user.phonenr = 2222555;
    }

    public submitnr() {
    if (this.user.phonenr === undefined)
    {
    console.log("fucking undefined why ??????");
    console.log(this.user.phonenr);
    }
    else
    {
    console.log("Its defined so why getting error!!!!!!????!??!!?");
    console.log(this.user.phonenr);
    }
    }
    }
```

user.ts:

```
    export class User {
    phonenr: number | undefined;
    }
```

user.service.ts:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { User } from './user';


    @Injectable()
    export class UserService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public register(user: User) {
    console.log(user.phonenr);
    }
    }
```

The part "user.phonenr" within the "login.component.html" always throws error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'phonenr' of undefined

Just to mention the If-instruction of submitnr() runs into the defined part.

I hope I provided all neccessary code. If not let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct, I only can suggest you add `*ngIf="user"` to the input, even that it does not directly fix the issue, it might help

Comment: Wow this worked. Dunno why and would appreciate an explanation.But it works.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

And... if you replace the class to interface?

Comment: While replacing interface with class it works.
Since I am a programming novice I'm not sure if that is the best solution for my issue.

Comment: Nice, perfect :)

Comment: I recommended to use the interfaces to transport data and use the classes to execute the logical/code.

Comment: I took the other solution by @Nguyen Phong Thien. Nevertheless thank you for your help and time.